# How to have column with character value equal to the enclosing character value in mysql load data in file

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

I'm using mysqlimport,which uses LOAD DATA INFILE command. My question is the following: Assume I have `--fields-enclosed-by='"'`, and that I have column with values which have double quoted string, such as `"5" object"` (which stands for 5 inches). The problem is that when mysql encounter the double quote string after the 5, it treats it as the enclosing character, and things are messed up. How to use mysqlimport with such values? I don't want to just use another character to enclosing, because this other character as well may occur in the data. So what is a general solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is will be different this way to import csv.

To solve above issue in another way,

1. Export or get or convert old data into sql format rather than csv format.
2. Import the same sql data using mysql command line tool.

   mysql -hservername -uusername -p'password' dbname < 'path to you sql imported file.sql'

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use csv format as it is very fast.